# Creating a List (array) of data from Firebase in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter, I want to make just a regular list (not list view) in my code to use it for search delegate. So if my data base looks like

[image]

How do I create a list of names, for example?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
   List<String> names = [];
    
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Doctors").get().then((value) {
       value.docs.foreach((item) {
          names.add(item.get("name"));
       });
    });
```